# Create eloquent relationships for Table with foreign keys to Pivot table - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a pivot table (builder_project) which I'm using on a many-to-many relationship between the '**projects**' and '**builders**' tables. And everything is working fine to this point.

However, I would like users to be able to add '**notes**' to the pivot table (**builder_project**) and because many notes should be able to be added I created a table called '**notes**' which has a **one-to-many relationship** with the pivot table.

I tried creating a model for the pivot table, however; when I try to access the method within the pivot model, I'm getting the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'notes.' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: select * from `builder_project` where exists
>   (select * from `notes` where `builder_project`.`project_projectID` =
>   `notes`.``))

This is the code for my pivot model:

```
namespace Estimating;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class Builder_project extends Pivot
{


    protected $table = "builder_project";

    protected $primaryKey = 'project_projectID'; // I need to add the other primary key here but I undestand it's not possible on Laravel
    protected $fillable = [
        'project_projectID',
        'builder_builderID',
        'note',

    ];
    // One to many relationships
    /**
     * 
     */
    public function test()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Estimating\Builder_project_note');
    }

}
```

This is the model for Builder_project_note:

```
<?php

namespace Estimating;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Builder_project_note extends Model
{
    //Determines which database table to use, in this case 'projects' table
    protected $table = "notes";

    protected $primaryKey = 'noteID';
    protected $fillable = [
        'project_projectID',
        'builder_builderID',
        'note',

    ];

    // One to many relationships
    /**
     * Get the status that owns the project.
     */
    public function test()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(
            'Estimating\Builder_project'); // I know that here I need an ID from Builder_project pivot table - but I have a composite key!;
    }


}
```

And this is how I'm trying to get the data from my controller and I get the error:

```
public function editBuilderProject(Request $request, $builderID, $projectID)
    {
        $browserDetails = new Agent();
        $project = Project::find($projectID); 
        $builder = Builder::find($builderID);

        $builder_project_statuses = Builder_project_status::all();

        $builder_project_note = Builder_project::has('test')->get();

        dd($builder_project_note);



        return view('projects/edit-builder-project', compact('browserDetails', 'project','builder', 'builder_project_statuses', 'builder_project_note'));
        //return  $projectID."  ". $builderID;
    }
```

I would appreciate if anyone can point me to the right direction with this and my apologies if I'm not being clear enough - this is my first post here :)

I've uploaded a sample of my database model:
[Database Model example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEVhZ.png)

Comment: Would you please share `Builder_project_note` model also!

Comment: @RashedHasan - Thanks for your comment, Rashed - I've added that to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel does not like primary keys based upon multiple columns. You need to add its own builder_project.id column (in your pivot table) which will be the field used by your notes table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jorge - I tried to implement your suggestion; however, because **'project_projectID'** and **'builder_builderID'** are acting as composite keys, I can't add another primary key with auto-increment as I get an error. I also tried making both of those columns non-primary keys but still can't make the new **'builder_project.id'** column auto-increment.